# jquery validation equalto not working in ASP.net content page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, unobtrusive-validation

I have two textboxes for password and confirm password. But the validation using Jquery validation plugin is not working. My controls are in Content page.

```
 <asp:textbox TextMode="Password" runat="server" ID="txtPassword" required="True"  class="form-control"></asp:textbox>


 <asp:textbox TextMode="Password" runat="server" ID="txtConfPassword" required="True" equalto= "ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPassword"  class="form-control"></asp:textbox>
```

I have even tried

```
equalto='<%=txtPassword.UniqueID %>' and equalto='<%=txtPassword.ClientID %>'
```

but its not working. My script is in master page as follows

```
function setFormValidation(id) {
          $(id).validate({
              highlight: function (element) {
                  $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-danger');
                  $(element).closest('.form-check').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-danger');
              },
              success: function (element) {
                  $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-danger').addClass('has-success');
                  $(element).closest('.form-check').removeClass('has-danger').addClass('has-success');
              },
              errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                  $(element).closest('.form-group').append(error);
              },
          });
      } 

    $(document).ready(function() {
          setFormValidation('#form1');
});
```

All other validations are working fine. I understand the error happens when the id of the textbox changes in content page.

please help.

**edit 1**

I have tried by adding the following script in master page.

```
$(id).validate({
                  rules: {
                      '<%= this.ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("txtPassword").UniqueID %>': {
                          required: true,
                          rangelength: [6, 15]
                      },
                      '<%= this.ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("txtConfPassword").UniqueID %>': {
                          required: true,
                          equalTo: '#<%= this.ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("txtPassword").ClientID %>'
                      }
                  },
                  messages: {

                      '<%= this.ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("txtPassword").UniqueID %>': {
                          required: "This field is required.",
                          rangelength: "Minimum 6 characters required"
                      },

                      '<%= this.ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("txtConfPassword").UniqueID %>': {

                          equalTo: "Please enter the same password again"
                      }
                  },
                  highlight: function (element) {
                      $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-danger');
                      $(element).closest('.form-check').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-danger');
                  },
                  success: function (element) {
                      $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-danger').addClass('has-success');
                      $(element).closest('.form-check').removeClass('has-danger').addClass('has-success');
                  },
                  errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                      $(element).closest('.form-group').append(error);
                  },
              })
```

It works fine for a specific page (say user.aspx). but when i navigate to any other page it will throw error 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
on  `'<%= this.ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("txtPassword").UniqueID %>':` 
because that control wont be there in the content page

i have tried to put if else condition in master page as

```
if (window.location.pathname == "/admin/AddUser.aspx") {
```

still it throws error

Comment: Please check this [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ee01e6/jquery-validation-with-Asp-Net-web-form/)

Comment: The issue i am facing is that my validate method is written in my master page. @jishansiddique please refer my edit

Comment: Please check in browser console may be some error occurred?

Comment: @jishansiddique. Its  a server error since the control txtPassword not present in any other page

Comment: Ya, I got the point you need to set one content placeholder in your master page and use it in your current page and modified the master page content place holder in the current page and set the validation code that selection hope it's work please try.

Comment: @jishansiddique. i didnt get you. can u elaborate

Answer (score 0):

Try equalTo="**#txtPassword**"

```xml
<asp:TextBox TextMode="Password" runat="server" ID="txtPassword" required="True"  class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox TextMode="Password" runat="server" ID="txtConfPassword" required="True" equalTo="#txtPassword" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
```

**Or in case using Validate rules**

Markup

```xml
<asp:TextBox TextMode="Password" runat="server" ID="txtPassword" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox TextMode="Password" runat="server" ID="txtConfPassword" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
    function setFormValidation(id) {
        $(id).validate({
            rules: {
                txtPassword: {
                    required: true
                },
                txtConfPassword: {
                    required: true,
                    equalTo: '#txtPassword' // '#<%= txtPassword.ClientID %>' // this would work too
                }
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        setFormValidation('#form1');
    });
</script>
```

For more information about the validation check out [jQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)

**Update**

I've just realized in Master/Content Page is slightly different, your code is correct, prepend a pound sign to the id defined in the EqualTo:

```xml
<asp:TextBox TextMode="Password" runat="server" ID="txtConfPassword" required="True" equalto="#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPassword" class="form-control">
```

Comment: Thanks. I have given ClientIDMode="Static" to password textbox and used equalto="#txtPassword" .. and it works fine,,,

Comment: As long as you ensure the IDs are unique when ClientIDMode set to static, it is okay. However, if your application grows, you might face problems with duplicate IDs.